# TSQL Filter in sproc failing on numeric conversion

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, filtering

I have a sub-query that returns a value.  If that value is greater than a range selected by the outside query, it should return the highest value of the outside query.

Given the following:

```
DECLARE @ExternalPixelValue VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SecondsTriggerValue INT
DECLARE @Trigger INT

SELECT TriggerValue
FROM vw_ContainerBehaviouralPixels
WHERE TriggerValue < 9000

SELECT 
     @ExternalPixelValue = ExternalPixelValue,
     @SecondsTriggerValue = CONVERT(INT, TriggerValue), 
     @Trigger = SUM(p.LastEventTimeSpan) 
FROM 
     PageVisitEvents p 
     RIGHT JOIN 
     vw_ContainerBehaviouralPixels vwc ON p.AccountContainerID = vwc.AccountContainerID
WHERE
     vwc.SystemBehaviouralSegmentID = 2         -- minimum time on site
     AND 
     CONVERT(INT, vwc.TriggerValue) < (SELECT 99999)
GROUP BY
     ExternalPixelValue, TriggerValue

SELECT @ExternalPixelValue, @SecondsTriggerValue, @Trigger
```

The first query returns values: 10, 30,  60, 90, 180, 300, 360.

Now, putting in a value in the subquery of 11 returns 10; anything between 31 and 60 returns 30, and so forth.  Problem is that when I enter anything in 180, 90 is always returned.  When I change the table value from 90 to 99, still, only 99 is returned.

TriggerValue is VARCHAR(512) which is why the conversion up there.  If figured the filter is recognizing the character, and not the numeric value.  However after using CONVERT and CAST, I'm still seeing the same issue.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: How does the first query work if `TriggerValue` is `varchar`? Shouldn't you convert there as well? And what you want is to return the max value bigger than the value that you put? Give some examples!

Comment: Add the view definition please. And learn to format so *we* can read it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are populating the variables

```
@ExternalPixelValue, @SecondsTriggerValue, @Trigger
```

over and over, so in the end, you have no control of the values they contain (the value from the last read)

If you write a syntax like that, make sure you only get 1 result for each variable or that you don't care which result is chosen.

Comment: Thank you for the tips.  After I changed the query to return all values  I found the problem - the two that were mentioned.  90 was the last result being returned, and because I was not converting TriggerValue to INT it was ordering them by character, and not numerically.  Fixed, thanks.

Comment: I also selected the TOP(1) in DESC order.